# Compare User Imputed Data to Pivot Table

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I am attempting to use an "IF" function to compare a data value from an inventory list in a pivot table with a user editable cell next to the pivot(for a physical inventory count).

```
=IF(GETPIVOTDATA("CurrentInventoryQuantity",B8)=G8,TRUE,FALSE)
```

This code returns an #REF! error.

I have to store the inventory data in a pivot so that it can dynamically add new rows as needed.

Any tips on how to get Excel to compare the data?

Comment: Come with your pivot table and data.

Comment: GETPIVOTDATA can only reference the Values area of a PivotTable. Your GETPIVOTDATA as written does nothing but reference the total value of the PivotTable. It's hard to give you alternatives that may help, because you haven't given us much to go on. Please clarify your question and post a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try using just the cell reference instead of GetPivotData.